# Range.Find doesn't find until makro is reset, paused and reset again

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

I recently got to work on an old Project of an colleague to get rid of bugs. Main Problem is, that in one Sub he shall count some numbers on sheets. But until i reset, paused and reset the Code, he doesn't count a thing. After some hours i realized, that he doesn't even find the beginning row in the first place, that  *startrow* and *endrow* are returned as Nothing. (*startDate* and *endDate* are fine and filled)

But if I reset, pause and reset the code manually again (over the VBA controls) then it works just fine, even if i change sheets etc. Only if i close and open it up there is this bug again (yes I tried deactivatet the opening makro, didn't help).

```
Dim startDate As String, endDate As String
For i = 1 To UBound(auftraegeVar, 1)
    ' Adopt range to be looked in for each order according to user specified months
    Set startrow = Worksheets(auftraegeVar(i)).Range("A1:A200").Find(what:=startDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    Set endrow = Worksheets(auftraegeVar(i)).Range("A1:A200").Find(what:=endDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
Next i
```

Edit:
Here is the module after applying the changes that @shairado suggested. Everything runs fine when startrow and endrow are ranges and with Set as above (except for the fact, that he always set them as nothing [i observed the variables], except i reset,pause and reset the makros). But now (If find returns Nothing, i get the Error 91 on find(bla).row, therefore the if part)

```
Public Sub HourCounting(auftraegeVar As Variant)

Dim indices As Range
Dim startrow As Integer, endrow As Integer
Dim startDate As String, endDate As String

'Do stuff that works
' Get start and end month in which to look for names
startDate = Worksheets("Main").cmbPastDate.Value
endDate = Worksheets("Main").cmbCurrentDate.Value

' Get start and end month in which to look for names
startDate = CDate(Worksheets("Main").cmbPastDate.Value)
endDate = CDate(Worksheets("Main").cmbCurrentDate.Value)


' ------------------- Search in all the workbooks for names, orders and months -------------------
For i = 1 To UBound(auftraegeVar, 1)
    ' Adopt range to be looked in for each order according to user specified months
    If Worksheets(auftraegeVar(i)).Range("A:A").Find(what:=startDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing Then
        startrow = 0
    Else
        startrow = Worksheets(auftraegeVar(i)).Range("A:A").Find(what:=startDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).row
    End If
    If Worksheets(auftraegeVar(i)).Range("A:A").Find(what:=endDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing Then
        endrow = 0
    Else
        endrow = Worksheets(auftraegeVar(i)).Range("A:A").Find(what:=endDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).row
    End If

    ' Do stuff in Loops that works 
Next i
End Sub
```

The Worksheet contains at the A1:A200 formulae that returns the first of a certain Month. Its formatted to Display only MMM YY. This is the same structure as my searchTerms (startDate and endDate).
If I try the search manually It works.

Comment: Just in case: auftraegeVar isnt empty either and gives the right worksheet names

Comment: according to your code `startrow` and `endrow` are `Range`s, right ? cause you are using the `Set`.  If you realy want to find the row, then use `startrow = Worksheets(auftraegeVar(i)).Range("A1:A200").Find(what:=startDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Row` , and define `Dim startrow As Long`

Comment: My suspicions go to that *idleTimer running in the background*. What is that> some VBA code launched at startupt? Could you please provide more details?

Comment: @ShaiRado Yes, startrow and endrow are Ranges. I will try your suggestion tomorrow and keep you updated.

Thanks for the fast suggestions :)

Comment: @A.S.H The idleTimer is just some timer which displays a MsgBox after 300 sec. This is not the problem. (Basically it's and VBA Sub). 
It was one of my first ideas that, this stupid timer is the root of all evil, but the error occured even after deleting the timer.

Comment: @shairado I tried as you said and now I get the 91 Error 'Object variable or with block variable not set' on  

    startrow = Worksheets(auftraegeVar(i)).Range("A1:A200").Find(what:=star‌​tDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Row

Comment: @TarrGrauzorn i meant first define `Dim startrow As Long` and then it should work

Comment: yeah i did this as well @shairado

Comment: @TarrGrauzorn I need more info to help you debug, can you post the rest of your code ? maybe also the structure of your worksheet ?

Comment: @shairado i just posted the full module in my question. The structure of the asked worksheets are fine, all ranges and names are okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Error: Type-Mismatch with the Values in the searched range. Phew. I gonna get myself some coffee. Thanks for helping :)